# How to create test data in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Hi i am working on rails app with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have to test my forgot_password controller there is a method which validates if the email id is presnt in the database or not.

```
forgot_password_controller.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ForgotPasswordController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.find_by_email(forgot_password_params[:email])
        unless user.blank?
      render json: {}, status: 200
    else
      render json: {}, status: 404
    end
  rescue StandardError
    render json: {}, status: 500
  end

    private

  def forgot_password_params
    permitted = %i[email]
    params.require(:data)
          .require(:attributes)
          .permit(permitted)
          .transform_keys(&:underscore)
  end
end
```

I want to test my api. i have written unit testing as follows:-

```
forgot_password_controller_spec.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

describe ForgotPasswordController do
  before do
    User.create!(email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
                 password: 'pass',
                 password_confirmation: 'pass')
  end

  describe 'POST create' do
    subject { post :create, params: params }

    context 'when email is found' do
      let(:params) do
        { data: { attributes: { email: 'xyz@gmail.com' } } }
      end

      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(200) }
    end

    context 'when email is not found' do
      let(:params) do
        { data: { attributes: { email: 'xyz2@gmail.com' } } }
      end

      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(404) }
    end

    context 'when wrong params passed' do
      let(:params) do
        { data: '' }
      end

      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(500) }
    end
  end
end
```

Now i want to create test data with 'let'
 like

```
let(:user) { instance_double('user') }
let(:save_result) { true }
```

How can i create user with let please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into using FactoryBot aka FactoryGirl as it makes writing that stuff out easier. But for your case this should be what your looking for:

```
let(:user) { User.create!(email: 'xyz@gmail.com', password: 'pass', password_confirmation: 'pass') }
```

If you had FactoryBot, you could simplify that with:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
```

Or possibly for better performance, if you don't actually need a record created but simply built:

```
let(:user) { build_stubbed(:user) }
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not using FactoryBot i also tried let(:user) { User.create!(email: 'xyz@gmail.com', password: 'pass', password_confirmation: 'pass') } bud didnot work. it doesnot create any user.

Comment: i also tried let!(:user) { User.create email: 'saddam@mivi.com.au', password: 'password',password_confirmation: 'password' } it works but i got an error RSpec/LetSetup: Do not use let! for test setup.

Comment: That sounds like rubocop complaining, instead of using `let()` just declare regular ruby inside the block. See http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/LetSetup

Comment: hey i have created a scope to find user with email but when i run my test case it always find the user even there is no record with id. please help

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you update your question with new code?

Comment: @awsmsid, as @dft mentioned, it is recommended to use `FactoryBot` or similar library to create your test data. Initially you may get away with creating objects via AR, but over time you'll feel the pain of not using data factories.

Comment: I find the second code example `let(:user) { create(:user) }` does not reveal the true amount of coding and work that goes into using FactoryBot. You cannot write that line of code without defining the factory for `:user`, which is equivalent to the first code example where AR is used. The advantage of FactoryBot is that the `:user` factory can be reused over and over in different places. But then... so could a method call. I think more explanation about the benefits of Factorybot would be useful. But then, the OP isn't about FB at all.